# Generic CSS rule for Class and Specific for ID?

Tags: css

I have a class named containner that has a lot of rules common to a lot of divs but I also want to get some specific details to those divs. I wonder if I can do something like this:

```
.containner {
   common rules
}

.containner, #somedivid {
   specific to some div rule
}
```

Cheers

Comment: If the answers below don't work for you, please post your HTML here

Comment: Thank you very much but I have found a solution that does work. I have commented bellow.

Answer (score 2):

To select an element inside your container, do this

```
.containner #somedivid{}
```

A comma will just style both elements individually, the CSS I posted can be used to be quite specific on a selector, using itself and however many parents it has.

```
.containner, #somedivid{color: red;}
```

is the same as

```
.containner{color: red;}
#somedivid{color: red;}
```

If you wanted all divs inside .containner to be 100x100px but one red and one blue, you can do something like this:

```
.containner *{border: 1px solid black;} /* Makes ALL elements inside .containner have a black border */
.containner div{width: 100px; height: 100px;} /* Makes all DIVS inside .containner 100x100px */
.containner div#somedivid{background-color: red;} /* Specific rules with a higher priority selector */
.containner #somedivid{background-color: blue;} /* Specific rules with a lower priority selector */
```

Comment: I want to write rules for some div that has the same behavior, get some specific details for the same divs as well... lets say that the color or something else for #somediv is different...

Comment: The proper solution is:

.conatinner, #divIdOne, #nDivId { 
   common rules 
}

#divIdOne {
   specific rules
}

#nDivId {
   specific rules
}
Thanks anyway...

Comment: @FCC-PT well you could do it by listing them all individually. I updated my answer which is a better way of doing it.